# Import Classes Java Problem Minecraft Plugin

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

I have a error when I try to start my Minecraft plugin.

[20:16:01 ERROR]: [OwnPlugin] Plugin OwnPlugin v1.1 has failed to register events for class org.plugin.net.ownplugin.DispenserEvent because org/bukkit/block/ShulkerBox does not exist.

I know why I am getting the error because i try to import a class that does not exist in the server version 1.8. I am trying to get the plugin to supported 1.7-1.15 but i got stuck here and do not really know what to do except creating a new class so it uses that class instead.

Thanks beforehand for the help!

Comment: Is that the latest version of `OwnPlugin`?

Comment: public Bukkit snapshot version is currently 1.15: https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/SPIGOT/repos/bukkit/browse/pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use reflection to archive this.
Here is a tutorial -> https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/tutorial-writen-how-to-use-reflection.41413/;